# How many ways different sets of values can be chosen for the $x_s$ , if $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 20$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

> Your statistics teacher announces a twenty-page reading assignment on Monday that is to be finished by Thursday morning. You intend to read the first $x_1$ pages Monday, the next $x_2$ pages Tuesday, and the final $x_3$ pages Wednesday, where $x_1+x_2+x_3=20$, and each $x_i\geq1$.
>
> In how many ways can you complete the assignment? That is, how many different sets of values can be chosen for $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$?

Attempt: I am learning $nC_k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. Then it seems there are $3$ distinct number of pages, namely: $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. And number of ways to form combinations of size $20$. I don't understand. I have not learned about other ways, so I have to use $nC_k$.

Comment: There are two important pages: the last page you read on Monday, and the last page you read on Tuesday.  These must also be among the first 19 pages, because you must read the last page on Wednesday.  How many ways are there to pick those two important pages, from the 19 pages that aren't last?

Comment: So, are you asking for an explanation of Stars and Bars and how it applies?...

Comment: No. I can't use that method.

Comment: There are two ways to pick this two important pages. So the last page is not very important?

Comment: The last page is "important" but we already know where it is.  And there's quite a few more than two ways to pick the other important pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked the condition that we're supposed to read a page per day.  In that case, we only need $19$ squares:

$$\boxed{\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square}$$

Now we write down that we're going to read $4,6,10$ as follows:

$$\boxed{\square\square\square\blacksquare\square\square\square\square\square\blacksquare\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square}$$

We're taking it for granted that we're going to read one page, and now the number of white boxes count how many *extra* pages we intend to read.

---

OLD ANSWER: (still worth keeping, as it solves the case where we are allowed to read nothing on some days)

Mark 22 spaces on a piece of paper: $$\boxed{\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square}$$

Say that we read for $4$ pages, $6$ pages, then $10$ pages.  We can represent that by blocking out two places:

$$\boxed{\square\square\square\square\blacksquare\square\square\square\square\square\square\blacksquare\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square\square}$$

We can interpret this as something like, "Read four pages, then go to sleep, then read six pages, then go to sleep, then read ten pages."

So how many ways are there of coloring in these little black boxes?

Comment: There are 2! ways ?

Comment: @user9273 Of doing what?  I only see one way of making those _particular_ black markings.  I am asking you how many different possible ways there are to make two black marks on this strip.

Comment: We have to select 2 out of 22 spaces of the piece of paper. So 2_C_22?

Comment: Be careful: there's a restriction here, we must read *at least one* page on each of the three days.

Comment: So we must subtract 22-3 = 19? So 2_C_19? Please can someone help me understand why? This problem is quite hard. Thanks.

Comment: @user9273 You are correct.  I have added some explanation that takes into account Dan's warning.  Let me know if there's anything I should elaborate on, but it sounds like you're thinking about this the right way.